# Writing IBM Domino applications in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I have a question to people who are writing programs in Domino Designer. I don't like it, really and I'm searching how to write apps for that platform in Intellij? Does somebody have experience in moving project from DDE to IntelliJ? I wan't to do this because my actual projects doesn't use XPages for front-end.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a survey/opinion poll.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible. A majority of the design elements needed for NSF- Development are stored in a proprietary binary format. There is no way to edit them in any other program than the Domino Designer.

You need to get familiar with this tool or abandon Domino development completely.

Comment: I don't want to move all work from domino designer to intellij. I want to have only full tips when I write code and then i can build it in domino designer.